# mysql result rows more than table rows

Tags: mysql

SQL Query:

```
SELECT * FROM `pet_info`
LEFT JOIN `lostpets` ON `pet_info`.`id` = `lostpets`.`petid`
LEFT JOIN `pet_images` ON `pet_info`.`id` = `pet_images`.`petid`
LEFT JOIN `dog_breeds` ON `dog_breeds`.`id` = CASE WHEN `pet_info`.`pet_cat` = 1 THEN `dog_breeds`.`id` END
LEFT JOIN `cat_breeds` ON `cat_breeds`.`id` = CASE WHEN `pet_info`.`pet_cat` = 2 THEN `cat_breeds`.`id` END
```

only 3 rows in pet_info table but when running query then it displaying more than 183 rows. more than 183 rows is in cat_breeds and dog_breeds table. why it apperaring 183 rows please help em How can I display all rows that in pet_info table.

Comment: Why would you expect at most 3 rows? The join is the Cartesian product between the tables, filtered by your where clause, it can have any amount of result rows.

Comment: @AnoE because only 3 rows in pet_info table and I want to display all records of pet_info table. Not extra rows.

Comment: Can you post a desc of the tables?

Comment: @shahrushabh, again... The select does not bother what You want, but it does what it does. To debug it, pluck it apart. Reduce it to only one table, look how many results you get. Then add another table. And so on.